# Why can Laplace’s Equation have a Green’s Function?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, greens-function

On the Wiki page for Green’s Functions, it states that a Green’s Function is an impulse response to an inhomogeneous source term of a differential equation. But, then I read elsewhere that the kernel for Laplace’s Equation is
$$G(x;y)=-\frac{1}{4\pi |x-y|}.$$
But, how can this be if Laplace’s Equation is homogenous? There can be no response. Finding the kernel is simple enough, but I’m struggling to explain this inconsistency.

Comment: The Green's function is really for the related Poisson equation, it solves $\Delta u = \delta$ (up to a sign). However, the Green's function for the Poisson equation is closely related to the solution of boundary value problems for the Laplace equation.

Comment: Indeed, as @Ian says, there is some abuse of language/terminology here, since the literal Laplace's equation is homogeneous. What is meant is the inhomogeneous version, often called Poisson's equation, with a target function/distribution on the other side, as opposed to the $0$ for the literal Laplace's equation.